# Many function is unresolved after Android Studio Chipmunk(11.0.12) Update

Tags: android, android-studio

There is no problem with all codes before the update.
But After the update, many functions are unresolved.
[My Android Studio version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzTmo.png)

 [error code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOilw.png) 
 [error code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Muy.png) 
 [error code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkHhA.png) 
All error contents are Unresolved reference:~~.
[my dependencies 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIytG.png) 
[my dependencies 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfn8P.png) 
There are my dependencies.
There is an error in the code, but the build works fine.
What's the problem?

Comment: Try rebuilding your project.

Comment: I've tried it many times. But it hasn't been fixed. [@GSutey]

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is unable to generate project files. Change the room dependencies(if being used) to '2.4.2' and upgrade your gradle to 7.0+

Also go to Android Studio-> preferences-> Build, version...-> Build tools-> Gradle and change the Gradle JDK to 11.